# How do I use a Bash variable (string) containing quotes in a command?

Tags: bash

Failing, simplified example:

```
FLAGS='--archive --exclude="foo bar.txt"'
rsync $FLAGS dir1 dir2
```

I need to include the quotes as if the command was like this:

```
rsync --archive --exclude="foo bar.txt" dir1 dir2
```

Comment: Related: [Pass arguments to function exactly as-is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78470/6860).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Short answer: see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) ("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!").

Long answer: Putting commands (or parts of commands) into variables and then getting them back out intact is complicated.  When the shell expands a variable on the command line, if the variable was in double-quotes it's not parsed; if it was not in quotes, spaces in it are parsed as argument breaks, but quotes and escape are not parsed.  In either case, putting quotes in the variable's value does nothing useful.

Usually, the best way to do this sort of thing is using an array instead of a simple text variable:

```
FLAGS=(--archive --exclude="foo bar.txt")
rsync "${FLAGS[@]}" dir1 dir2
```

Comment: Holy Jezus it works!

Comment: Thanks! Anything without intermediate variable (and not modifiying the command itself like with `eval` prefix) is impossible, right?

Comment: @mvorisek If I understand what you mean (using a non-array variable, and no `eval` or equivalent), then it's impossible.

Answer (score 8):

**eval** is another option:

```
$ x="'a b'"
$ printf '%s,%s' $x
'a,b'
$ eval printf '%s,%s' $x
a b
```

See also:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38440/why-does-bash-variable-expansion-retain-quotes
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454526/bash-variable-containing-multiple-args-with-quotes

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can create an alias for your command:

```
alias myrsync='rsync --archive --exclude="foo bar.txt"'
myrsync dir1 dir2
```

Comment: `alias myrsync="rsync $FLAGS"` is more correct answer to the specific question IMO

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `eval` to parse into an array. Obviously this will let whoever controls the string doing whatever they want.

```bsh
FLAGS='--archive --exclude="foo bar.txt"'
eval "FLAGS=($FLAGS)"
rsync "${FLAGS[@]}" dir1 dir2
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @cbix, using an alias is a nice solution in this case.

Don't forget to allow aliases expansion in scripts by using the line

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

As explained here https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-make-alias-command-work-in-bash-script-or-bashrc-file/ it is stated in the man page of bash:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
> expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt

Answer (score -2):

I don't see the problem :

```
$ FLAGS='--archive --exclude="foo bar.txt"'
$ echo $FLAGS
--archive --exclude="foo bar.txt"
```

Maybe you need to quote again the value :

```
$ rsync "$FLAGS" dir1 dir2
```

Comment: `echo` isn't showing what you think it is.  Try `printargs() { printf "'%s' " "$@"; echo; }; printargs $FLAGS; printargs "$FLAGS"` to see why neither of these options work.

Comment: @GordonDavisson But printargs() prints same output if no arguments or if one empty string argument.