# Bash: if [ tar = error ]

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

I want a shell script to write a message depending on whether `tar` succeeds or fails, but this script doesn't work correctly:

```
TAR=$(tar -cf Archiv.tar myfolder/ myotherfolder/)
if [ ! "$TAR" = "/dev/null" ]; then
   echo "success"
else
  echo "error - no such Directory or file"
fi
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You will have to explain what the script is supposed to do and what "doesn't work" means.  I can't understand at all why you would want to print "success" if tar prints "/dev/null" and the other message otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a situation where `tar` will output `/dev/null` to signal an error, which is how your code attempts to detect the error. This is the correct way to check for errors:

```
if tar -cf Archiv.tar myfolder/ myotherfolder/
then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "error - no such Directory or file"
fi
```

You probably don't need the `else` case because `tar` itself will complain in that case. If your use of `/dev/null` was supposed to suppress `tar` complaints so that you can substitute your own message, then the first line should be:

```
if tar -cf Archiv.tar myfolder/ myotherfolder/ > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Notice that we're not using square brackets here. That's actually an alias for a built-in shell command called [`test(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) which does logical operations and returns 0 or nonzero to signal success or failure, respectively. `if` in turn checks for this 0/nonzero return, so in order to check for the success of a program like `tar` that returns nonzero on failure, you don't need to involve `test` or its alias `[`.

If you were trained on a programming language that requires some kind of punctuation surrounding the `if` expression so that the lack of punctuation bothers you here, you could rewrite the first line like this:

```
tar -cf Archiv.tar myfolder/ myotherfolder/
if [ $? = 0 ]
```

These two lines together do the same thing a the version above because the shell built-in variable `$?` holds the status code of that last program run.

This is perhaps clearer, but a bit wasteful.

Comment: Thank you Warren Young! And can I "process" assign? Example: if [ $TAR = 0 ]

Comment: @Jannyeis: I'm not sure what you mean. If you run `tar` inside `$()` like in your original code, you are capturing its output. So, comparing that output to 0 is also not likely to do what you want. You're interested in the [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) here, not the text output of the program.

Answer (score 1):

As usual there is more then one way to do what you were trying to.
This is a (maybe compact) way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
TAR_COMMAND='tar -cf Archiv.tar myfolder/ myotherfolder/ 2>/dev/null'
MSG_OK='### Work well DONE ### '   # A more common way to use a variable
MSG_ERR='### OPS IT FAILS ###  '    

$TAR_COMMAND && echo $MSG_OK || echo $MSG_ERR
```

**Short notes**

- If you have **no need to store the exit status** (or the exit code) of your command you can use immediately after the operators **AND**, `&&`, and  **OR**, `||` <sup>[[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24685/66388)]</sup>.
  The logic: `cmd1 && cmd2`, `cmd2` will executed  only if `cmd1` exits without errors (with exit code `0`). 
  Instead with `cmd1 || cmd3`, `cmd3` will be executed only if `cmd1` will exits with an error (error code different from `0`).
- If, instead, you **want to store the exit code** of a command you have to do it  immediately after its execution, because with the next command execution this value will be updated. It's enough a variable assignation

  ```
  mycommand               # you execute your command
  ExitCodeToUseLater=$?   # So I can use it later in the script
  # ... other stuffs ...
  [ $ExitCodeToUseLater = 0  ]  && echo "It was gone ok " 
  # ... again other stuffs ...
  [ $ExitCodeToUseLater = 0  ] || echo "# Never a time that it goes as I want"
  ```
- In bash scripting, as well as in the makefiles <sup>[[2a](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables-Simplify),[2b](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference)]</sup>,  you can find **a command** with many options **written in a variable** in order to make more readable the code (as you can see above for the `TAR_COMMAND` variable).  Writing in a shell the variable `$MyVar` it will be the same to write in the shell what is written inside <sup>[[3](https://superuser.com/a/679968/257269)]</sup>. It works in  a script too. You may have to pay attention to the bash expansion and substitution rules about which you can read more from `man bash`.
- `/dev/null` is the *Null device* <sup>[[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device)]</sup>,  *"a device file that discards all data written to it but reports that the write operation succeeded"*.  It can be used to give an empty input to a command (`</dev/null`) or to pass in "absolute silence" the standard output or the standard error <sup>[[5](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)]</sup>.

Comment: And how could you print the message **and** exit right after like `|| echo $MSG_ERR && exit -1` (which doesn't work)?

Comment: Did you tried `{...}`?  Check from command line: `(head /dev/urandom  | tar -cf archive.tar -T - 2>/dev/null || { /bin/echo "Error" && exit 3 ;}) ; echo $?` It answers me 3. But even `(head /dev/urandom  | tar -cf archive.tar -T - 2>/dev/null ||  echo "Error" && exit 3 ) ; echo $?` it answers me 3.  Ps> Note `(...)` is to execute in a subshell else when it exits it closes the terminal.

Comment: Yes I tried `{...}` but it didn't work. It seems, from my beginner's point of view, that `{...}` are made to "group something to be a global output" like `{...} > tt.txt` or `{...} | more`. Maybe my understanding is not good but anyway it didn't work.

Comment: Strange it should. Did you remember to put also the last `;` ? Did the previous examples work in your environment (hopefully a modern `bash`)? You can always __store the exit code__ (`ExitCodeToUseLater=$?`) and use this value after as a normal variable (check examples online)...